# Proving that solutions to nonlinear PDE are unique

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Consider the following nonlinear BVP:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - k \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \lambda e^{\alpha u} &= f  \\
u(0,t) &= T_0(t) \\
u(L,t) &= T_L(t) \\
u(x,0) &= u_0(x)
\end{align}

in some region $(0,L)\times (0,T)$, where $k$, $\lambda$, $\alpha$, $L$ and $T$ are all positive. I am interested in proving that if solutions exist, they are unique. The nonlinear term makes the usual energy method difficult. The best I can come up with is if $u$ and $v$ are solutions to the original BVP, and if $w = u - v$, then $w$ satisfies:

$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} - k \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2} = \lambda (e^{\alpha v} - e^{\alpha u}).$$
But from there I cannot make any progress towards showing the usual argument that $\int w^2 \ dx$ must be decreasing or constant in time, and thus $w = 0$.

I have spent some time looking into the J.C. Evans textbook, as well as the probably overkill [Handbook of Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations](https://www.crcpress.com/Handbook-of-Nonlinear-Partial-Differential-Equations-Second-Edition/Polyanin-Zaitsev/p/book/9781420087239), without noticing anything useful at first glance. How can I make some progress here?

Comment: You have $(u-v) (e^{\alpha u} - e^{\alpha v}) \ge 0$ and this should be enough to apply the energy method.

Comment: Oh of course, if $u \leq v$, then $(u - v)(e^{\alpha v} - e^{\alpha u}) \leq 0$, and if $u > v$, then $(u - v)(e^{\alpha v} - e^{\alpha u}) < 0$, so in all cases, $(u - v)(e^{\alpha v} - e^{\alpha u}) \leq 0$, and the energy method will proceed from there.